# show html elements based on user's role

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am trying to hide html elements from plain users such that only users.
I have  simple asp.net web form setup that makes use of roles provider and membership.

```
<li runat="server" id="li1" visible ='<%# HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin") %>'><a href="screeners.aspx"><span> Admin link</span></a></li>
```

I also am trying this without success:

```
<li runat="server" id="liAdminUsers" visible ='<%# isAdmin %>'><a  href="screeners.aspx"><span> The Hopper</span></a></li>
```

the code behind is:

```
public bool isAdmin =false;
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                isAdmin = Page.User.IsInRole("admin");
                       }
```

**update:** I know I can get it working by adding in the code behind:

```
liAdminUsers.Visible = false ;
```

but want a UI solution in the .aspx code

Comment: Can't you set the visibility of the elements in the code behind? You know the id of the element.

Comment: I could set each li server side to visible=false, but don't want to mix ui logic. the html should be able to be controlled by dynamically setting items based on method or value. I think either approach is a bit off or the life cycle may be off of the page load

Comment: you have to use Server side code only to set <li> visibility; I believe your flag is not set by the time page renders

Comment: Not sure if this matters in your case - but as a best-practice suggestion, you might consider hiding the entire `li` tag, rather than just setting it's `visibility`. This way, the list-item is removed server-side, rather than client-side (where it could just as easily be turned back on using a debugger window).

Comment: Please try changing the access modifier of isAdmin to protected in the code behind. That has worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [data-binding syntax `<%# ... %>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx(v=vs.71).aspx), so you need to call `Page.DataBind()`

You typically call DataBind() in your `Page_Load` method.

Answer (score 0):

I once did something similar using a custom XML file with an attribute indicating if roles were applied or not for a particular application link - and if so, another attribute containing the role name. The code-behind would then check the custom membership store using the logged-in users network identity for authorization checking.

Answer (score 0):

Write a static method in code behind to test the role

```
public static bool IsAdmin(){
   //chech and return true or false
}
```

In html call this method like

```
<li runat="server" id="liAdminUsers" visible ='<%# isAdmin() %>'>.....</li>
```

In this way you can control you logic like any other method.

Or you can directly set element visible false in your code behind

```
public static void IsAdmin(){
     var admin = ....; //check current user role;       
     liAdminUsers.Visible = admin;
}
```

Comment: tried but not working: <li runat="server" id="li2" visible ='<%# IsInAdmin () %>'><a class="ajax-link" href="AdminStatus.aspx"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i><span> Admin Status2</span></a></li>

Comment: public static bool IsInAdmin()
        {
            return false;
        }

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you formulate a class that will hide the said elements.

CSS

```css
hide-elements {
  display:none;
}

show-elements {
 display:block;
}
```

C# CodeBehind

```
public string isAdmin()
{
   if (condition == false)
   return "hidden-elements";
   else
   return "show-elements";
}
```

HTML code

```
<li runat="server" id="liAdminUsers" class='<%# isAdmin() %>'>.....</li>
```

Hope this help. :D (my first post)

Answer (score 0):

If you are reaching a variable from code behind, you need to use <%= isAdmin%> , not <%# isAdmin()%>

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue earlier and I solved it by declaring a protected variable in .aspx.cs file and directly using it in the aspx page.

Aspx Page:

```
<li runat="server" id="li1" visible ='<%# IsAdmin %>'>
    <a href="screeners.aspx"><span> Admin link</span></a>
</li>
```

Aspx.cs File:

```
protected bool IsAdmin = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

in aspx files you can try :

```
<% if (isAdmin()==true ) {  %>
your html codes and server controlls

<%}>
```

if isAdmin retruns true asp write yours codes in (your html codes and server controlls) your page.